# is it possible to email a particular piece of data from database without using view?

Tags: laravel-4

Here is my controller method:

```
Contact::create([
                       'name' => Input::get('name'),
                       'email' => Input::get('email'),
                       'confirmation_code' => $confirmation_code
                ]);


                Mail::send('blank', array('msg' =>'Welcome {{$name}}','name'=>Input::get('name'),'confirmation_code' => $confirmation_code), function($message){
                    $message->to(Input::get('email'), Input::get('name'))->subject(' ');
                });
```

Here is the Blank view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            {{ $msg }}
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The email is sent successfully. But the body is 'Welcome {{$name}}'. The value of {{$name}} is not sent with email. How to fetch the value of $name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant have blade variables within other variables - it doesnt work that way.

You need to change your code to this:

```
Mail::send('blank', array('msg' =>'Welcome '.e(Input::get('name')),'name'=>Input::get('name'),'confirmation_code' => $confirmation_code), function($message){
                    $message->to(Input::get('email'), Input::get('name'))->subject(' ');
                });
```

Or better yet - handle the message inside the view file itself, rather than passing it via a variable.